# PostgreSQL - Grouping by date gives sequential sums instead of grouped sums

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to do a pretty straightforward query with group by using a date but its giving sequential sums instead  of grouped sums

```
SELECT 
       sum(pit.preco) AS preco,
       sum(pit.quantidade) AS quantidade
FROM cliente c
LEFT JOIN erp_pedido ped ON ped.id_cliente = c.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN erp_pedido_it pit ON pit.id_pedido = ped.id_pedido

WHERE ped.tipo = 'C'    
  AND ped.id_cliente = 2

GROUP BY 
         ped.data_inicio ,
         c.nome,
         ped.id_cliente

ORDER BY ped.data_inicio desc,
         ped.id_cliente
```

it yelds:

```
2017-03-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  1.5000   ;  209.0000
2017-02-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  3.0000   ;  418.0000
2017-01-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  4.5000   ;  627.0000
2016-12-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  6.0000   ;  836.0000
2016-11-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  7.5000   ;  1045.0000
2016-10-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  9.0000   ;  1254.0000
2016-09-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  10.5000  ;  1463.0000
2016-08-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  12.0000  ;  1672.0000
2016-07-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  13.5000  ;  1881.0000
2016-06-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  15.0000  ;  2090.0000
2016-05-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  16.5000  ;  2299.0000
```

and i was expecting every row to be identical

```
PRECO   ; QUANTIDADE
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
```

I don't understand why it's summing every row sequentially

*the summed rows may vary in content, but in the test case they are just identical

Comment: Include the items from your `GROUP BY` in your `SELECT` list and it will shed light on your results.

Comment: first, why do you sum `preco` (price)? Second, why do you want to **show** every rows to be identical? it should be only **one row** with `preco` and sum(quantidade) for each group? Third, according to your result, it's a `right ` query results as you group by each date, so may you want to sum by `id_cliente` but display all `date`?

Comment: 1: because i want to show the total for the day ___ 
2: every row is identical because the data is identical in the item table, there could be a different row if someone entered a different item, it just  doesn't happens to be the case for this client (which is not invalid by any means) ___

3:I need the total of pit.preco for each date by client. if a client has  2 item with  price 10 for the dates 22/11 23/11 and 24/11 it should list  20,20,20 and not 20,40,60 like my query

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question what the issue is, your result shows 1 record per date and customer, which is what I'd expect since you're grouping by those fields.

Comment: @HartCO the problem is not the number of results, but the values on quantidade and preco_______ the value of PRECO is summed for each row.  for example :  date 03-01 is 1.5 , date 02-01 is 3.0, date 01-01 is 4.5....  it's stepping 1.5 for each row , while in the database every row totals to 1.5  for each date.
_____________
Think about a report broken by day , where you need to get the total of orders by that date for each client  .
(that's not really the case but it's near)

I'm probably just misusing group by really

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot issues like this when the underlying data isn't visible, perhaps if you change to select * without the group by you will gain insight on what is causing the unexpected value in the sum, try looking at a small raw sample before aggregation and see if you can make sense of it.

Comment: Your query is alright, I'd say your test data is where the problem lies. Also, if you're filtering by `erp_pedido.id_cliente` then it is pointless performing a LEFT JOIN on `erp_pedido`: change it to an INNER JOIN.